# How to see the java process that is using a port

Tags: mac-osx, port

I have a small Java ServerSocket application that is running on port 4444. I wanted to see the process using that port in my OSX terminal, and my first thought was to do the following:

`netstat -a | grep 4444` however, this doesn't give me any results.

`lsof -i :4444` and I get the following (correct) result:

```
COMMAND   PID        USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    66389 admin   18u  IPv6 0x1ae123a422ebe931      0t0  TCP *:krb524 (LISTEN)
```

Could someone tell me why netstat doesn't show the port but lsof does?

Answer (score 1):

Mac OSX is based on BSD so the `netstat` under Mac OSX will not be able to show you the pid/process name. As you already figured out, `lsof` is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: The version of Netstat that is included with Mac OSX does not interpret the `-p` flag as it does in other distributions (protocol instead of program), so while Netstat likely did not work for the reasons outlined below, `lsof` was still the correct way to go for the answer.

Netstat by default uses friendly names/definitions for ports (e.g., `ssh` instead of `22`). Add the `-n` flag to use numeric host addresses and port numbers. Additionally, add `-p` to show the PID and name of the program.

In summary: `netstat -anp | grep 4444` is probably what you would need.

Here's an example:

```
# netstat -anp | grep 10050
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1121/zabbix_agentd
```

Netstat will also print any other related network connections as well, not just sockets in the `LISTEN` state.